Module luamplib Warning: ! A secondary expression can't begin with `scaled'
Fiddling around with an example from "Drawing with Metapost" by Toby Thurston, p. 39 since a few days, but still stuck.  This example runs in plain METAPOST without luamplib-usage flawless (correct greek labels at the triangle angels), but when embedding it in a TeX-file with luamplib it fails with the following message I posted below the example-code. The problem seems to be with the second macro definition of mid_arc and the following label-definitions at the end and it's processing by lua? Especially the expression "char 13" results in strange behavior, if outcommenting this line or changing "char 13" to "char 14" the TeX-run finishes without printing the greek labels in the triangle, with the line it fails completely compiling with the Warning ... . What might be the reason?
The code of my failing example is as follows:
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
 
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{babel}

    \usepackage{luamplib}
   \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
   

   \begin{document}

   \begin{mplibcode}
    
  vardef freehand_through@#(expr a, b) =
  save t; pair t;
  t = @# * unitvector(b - a) rotated (4 + normaldeviate);
  a - t .. a {t} .. b {t} .. b + t
enddef;

vardef mid_arc@#(expr p, a, b) =
  save c; path c;
  c = fullcircle scaled (2*@#) shifted p cutbefore a cutafter b;
  point arctime 1/2 arclength c of c of c
enddef;

       beginfig(1);

  defaultfont := "eurm10"; color sepia; sepia = (0.44, 0.26, 0.08);

  pair A, B, C;
  A = (0,-30); B = (180,0);  C = (120,90);

  path a, b, c;
  a = freehand_through 7 (A, B);
  b = freehand_through 8 (B, C);
  c = freehand_through 6 (C, A);
 
  drawoptions(withcolor sepia);
  draw a; draw b; draw c;
 
  drawoptions(withcolor .67 blue);
  label.bot ("a", point 3/2 of a);
  label.rt  ("b", point 3/2 of b);
  label.ulft("c", point 3/2 of c);

  drawoptions(withcolor .5 red);
  label(char 11, mid_arc 16 (A, a, c)); 
  label(char 12, mid_arc 14 (B, b, a));
  label(char 13, mid_arc 14 (C, c, b));

  drawoptions();
  
endfig;    
 
   \end{mplibcode}

   \end{document}


Module luamplib Warning:
! A secondary expression can't begin with `scaled'.
<inserted text> 
                0
<to be read again> 
                   scaled
thelabel->...se:p=(EXPR3)infont.defaultfont.scaled
                                                  .defaultscale.fi;p.shifted...
<*> label(char 13, mid_arc 14 (C, c, b))
                                        ;
I'm afraid I need some sort of value in order to continue,
so I've tentatively inserted `0'. You may want to
delete this zero and insert something else;
see Chapter 27 of The METAFONTbook for an example.
>> 0
>> 1
! Not implemented: (known numeric)scaled(known numeric).
<to be read again> 
                   ;
thelabel->...t.defaultfont.scaled.defaultscale.fi;
                                                  p.shifted((EXPR4)+labeloff...
<*> label(char 13, mid_arc 14 (C, c, b))
                                        ;
I'm afraid I don't know how to apply that operation to that
combination of types. Continue, and I'll return the second
argument (see above) as the result of the operation.
>> unknown picture p
>> 1
! Equation cannot be performed (unknown picture=numeric).
<to be read again> 


Thanks for mention! -- the problem with this example is that it uses infont in the old fashioned way, but the OP was running it with \mplibtextextlabel{enable} which changes the infont operator so that labels are automatically processed through the enclosing LaTeX environment.  So to get this particular example to work you need to run it without that option.   So to get this:

Wrap up the source given in the document like this:
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
% \mplibtextextlabel{enable} <-- don't use for this one
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
    
vardef freehand_through@#(expr a, b) =
  save t; pair t;
  t = @# * unitvector(b - a) rotated (4 + normaldeviate);
  a - t .. a {t} .. b {t} .. b + t
enddef;

vardef mid_arc@#(expr p, a, b) =
  save c; path c;
  c = fullcircle scaled (2*@#) shifted p cutbefore a cutafter b;
  point arctime 1/2 arclength c of c of c
enddef;

beginfig(1);

  defaultfont := "eurm10"; color sepia; sepia = (0.44, 0.26, 0.08);

  pair A, B, C;
  A = (0,-30); B = (180,0);  C = (120,90);

  path a, b, c;
  a = freehand_through 7 (A, B);
  b = freehand_through 8 (B, C);
  c = freehand_through 6 (C, A);
 
  drawoptions(withcolor sepia);
  draw a; draw b; draw c;
 
  drawoptions(withcolor .67 blue);
  label.bot ("a", point 3/2 of a);
  label.rt  ("b", point 3/2 of b);
  label.ulft("c", point 3/2 of c);

  drawoptions(withcolor .5 red);
  label(char 11, mid_arc 16 (A, a, c)); 
  label(char 12, mid_arc 14 (B, b, a));
  label(char 13, mid_arc 14 (C, c, b));
  drawoptions();
  
endfig;    
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

This compiles without error (for me) using lualatex.   If you want to know more about the \mplibtextextlabel option, read section 12 of the docment, or check the latest luamplib documentation.
I shall add a suitable warning to this part of the doc.
Details
With the normal plain.mp format, when you use a label(s, z) macro, if the first argument s is not a <picture>, the macro will try to turn it into one by doing
picture p; p = s infont defaultfont scaled defaultscale;

so in regular mpost if you process this line
label(char 11, z);

the macro will try to make a text <picture> with
p = char 11 infont defaultfont scaled defaultscale;

and in our case that's good because we have set defaultfont := "eurm10" and so we get a <picture> of a nice alpha which happens to be char 11 in that font.
The primitive command infont is a dyadic command that takes two <string> arguments and produces a <picture>.   So "Don" infont "ptmr8r" will produce a <picture> with "Don" set in Times New Roman.
But if you set \mplibtextextlabel{enable} then luamplib redefines the meaning of infont so that the first argument is passed directly to the TEX() macro and the second argument is completely ignored.
So what you get when you expand label(s, z) with the option on is
p = TEX(char 11) scaled defaultscale;

this is syntactically OK, but useless because TEX(char 11) will produce an empty picture, so your label will be blank.
The baffling error that hit the OP, was caused by the char 13 line.  In what looks like a luamplib bug (dev team, I hope you are reading!) the expansion of TEX(char 13) is a <vacuous> instead of a <picture>, so MP has no target for the following scaled defaultscale part of the macro.  So....
label(char 13, z)

has expanded to
p = char 13 infont "eurm10" scaled defaultscale;

which (because of the option) has expanded to
p = TEX(char 13) scaled defaultscale;

which the TEX() macro expands to ...\hbox{^^M} but because
but char 13 = ^^M is the end of line character in TeX, TeX gets to process ..\hbox{ which gives a "missing } error".  Unfortunately the luamplib version of the TEX() macro does not handle this error well and returns a <vacuous> expression instead of a <picture>, so MP tries to process this:
p = scaled defaultscale;

which generates the error "A statement cannot begin with scaled".  This is admittedly pretty obscure.
I shall draw have drawn attention to this on the MP mailing list, and the team are planning to handle the error better so that their TEX() macro returns a <picture> in future.

The problem is that you used the wrong font mode. The code below works here with the shown output. I have used the Euler-Math opentype font for math, it seems more natural when you use "modern" things as luamplib.
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{luamplib}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Euler-Math.otf}

\begin{document}

\begin{mplibcode}

  vardef freehand_through@#(expr a, b) =
    save t; pair t;
    t = @# * unitvector(b - a) rotated (4 + normaldeviate);
    a - t .. a {t} .. b {t} .. b + t
  enddef;

  vardef mid_arc@#(expr p, a, b) =
    save c; path c;
    c = fullcircle scaled (2*@#) shifted p cutbefore a cutafter b;
    point arctime 1/2 arclength c of c of c
  enddef;

  beginfig(1);

  pair A, B, C;
  A = (0,-30); B = (180,0);  C = (120,90);

  path a, b, c;
  a = freehand_through 7 (A, B);
  b = freehand_through 8 (B, C);
  c = freehand_through 6 (C, A);

  color sepia; sepia = (0.44, 0.26, 0.08);
  drawoptions(withcolor sepia);
  draw a; draw b; draw c;

  drawoptions(withcolor .67 blue);
  label.bot ("a", point 3/2 of a);
  label.rt  ("b", point 3/2 of b);
  label.ulft("c", point 3/2 of c);

  drawoptions(withcolor .5 red);
  label("\(\alpha\)", mid_arc 16 (A, a, c));
  label("\(\beta\)", mid_arc 14 (B, b, a));
  label("\(\gamma\)", mid_arc 14 (C, c, b));

  drawoptions();

  endfig;

\end{mplibcode}

\end{document}



Apologies for down voting, but the color sepia was defined in the OP post.  And the problem is as I have explained it in my response.  Although clearly using the Euler-Math as you suggest is a good option in the modern world -- I don't think it was available when I first wrote the original example.

Haha, down votes actually amuse me, in particular when they are non-anonymous. I probably commented away sepia first while looking at the example and then forgot about that.
